# Merge unaligned DataFrames while filling with empty string

Tags: python, pandas, merge, alignment, concatenation

I have multiple DataFrames that I want to merge where I would like the fill value an empty string rather than nan. Some of the DataFrames have already nan values in them. concat sort of does what I want but fill empty values with nan. How does one not fill them with nan, or specify the fill_value to achieve something like this:

```
>>> df1
    Value1
0       1
1     NaN
2       3

>>> df2
    Value2
1       5
2       Nan
3       7

>>> merge_multiple_without_nan([df1,df2])
    Value1    Value2
0       1     
1     NaN       5
2       3       NaN
3               7
```

This is what concat does:

```
>>> concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
   Value1  Value2
0       1     NaN
1     NaN       5
2       3     NaN
3     NaN       7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find any function in concat or merge that would handle this by itself, but the code below works without much hassel:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value2': [1,np.nan,3]}, index = [0,1, 2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value2': [5,np.nan,7]}, index = [1, 2, 3])
# Add temporary Nan values for the data frames.
df = pd.concat([df1.fillna('X'), df2.fillna('Y')], axis=1)
df=
  Value2 Value2
0      1    NaN
1      X      5
2      3      Y
3    NaN      7
```

Step 2:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df=
  Value2 Value2
0      1
1      X      5
2      3      Y
3             7
```

Step 3:

```
df.replace(to_replace=['X','Y'], value=np.nan, inplace=True)
df=
  Value2 Value2
0      1
1    NaN      5
2      3    NaN
3             7
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `concat`, you can iterate over the DataFrames you merged, find the indices that are missing, and fill them in with an empty string.  This should work for concatenating an arbitrary number of DataFrames, as long as your column names are unique.

```
# Concatenate all of the DataFrames.
merge_dfs = [df1, df2]
full_df = pd.concat(merge_dfs, axis=1)

# Find missing indices for each merged frame, fill with an empty string.
for partial_df in merge_dfs:
    missing_idx = full_df.index.difference(partial_df.index)
    full_df.loc[missing_idx, partial_df.columns] = ''
```

The resulting output using your sample data:

```
  Value1 Value2
0      1       
1    NaN      5
2      3    NaN
3             7
```